# Error Could not resolve './components/Topbar/Topbar.jsx' from src/App.jsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, vite

**Hello, first, I would like to inform you that I am using Google translation to help me (in case there is any syntax error).**

I'm having a problem when deploying a project, when I use the command to build in VSCODE it completes normally, but when I tried to upload this deploy to a netlify, for example, it shows an import error.

I would like the help of someone who can help me. I got stuck in this error, and I'm trying to solve it for hours.

Addends:
I'm programming on my own, beginner level.
I'm using vite.
[image]

[Folder path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rENii.png)

App.jsx:

```
import Topbar from "./components/Topbar/Topbar.jsx";
import Basebar from "./components/Basebar/Basebar.jsx";
import Make from "./components/Make/Make.jsx";
import Manage from "./components/Manage/Manage.jsx";
import Subbar from "./components/Subbar/Subbar.jsx";
import Team from "./components/Team/Team.jsx";
import Why from "./components/Why/Why.jsx";
import Work from "./components/Work/Work.jsx";


function App() {


  return (
    <div>
        <Topbar />
        <Manage />
        <Subbar />
        <Team />
        <Make />
        <Work />
        <Why />
        <Basebar />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Topbar.jsx:

```
import styles from './topbar.module.css';

export default function Topbar() {
    return ( 
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                <div className={styles.logo} >
                    <span>team.flow</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.menu}>
                    <span>How it Works</span>
                    <span>Product</span>
                    <span>Pricing</span>
                    <span>Resources</span>
                    <span>Log in</span>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.get} >
                    <button>Get started free</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

1- I tried different ways of exporting, which solved the problem for the build in VSCODE, but it continued in netlify.

2- I used other sites to support my deploy.

Comment: "Could not resolve" means that the file wasn't found at the given path. Are you sure your filestructure matches your import statements, both in vscode and netlify?

Comment: I believe so, in the tests the site is normal, only in the construction of the build that presents this error. Folder path add.